# In what situation is a slant top register boot the preferred choice?

Tags: hvac

I see them sold all over the place but when I search for information on them it is almost like they don't exist. In what situation does it make sense to choose that style of register boot?

Comment: This is really an opinion based question and that would be off topic.

Comment: I don't think so, Ed. It's more a matter of necessity or convenience than prerogative.

Comment: If you are speaking of a heating register boot can you be more explicit and maybe show a picture of what you need explained.

Comment: Maybe I am thinking of it wrong but I was thinking of an add on. Not a tapered ductwork to the register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The slanted boot makes it easier to install near a sharply pitched roof. 
>  <sub>[source](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-8-in-x-8-in-to-7-in-Slant-Top-Insulated-Register-Box-with-Tabs-SIRB8X8X7/204160588)</sub>

> A slant top ceiling box provides an easy transition from round pipe or flexible duct to the air register near a sharply pitched roof. 
> <sub>[source](https://www.ecmdi.com/6-x-10-x-8-r8-insulated-slant-top-ceiling-box-16538)</sub>